# highcharts y axis not showing if graph is too wide, but only in certain browsers

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have six graphs inside a table; 2 to a row. Each graph is 600x600 and looks perfectly fine in Firefox. However when I view them in Chrome or Internet Explorer one graph in particular does not fully render as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W2sT.png. If I change the width of this graph from 600 to 500 it displays as it should. If I increase it above 500 at all, even to 505, it doesn't fully render. What could be causing this?

**edit: it also appears that taking out 'logarithmic' also allows the y axis to be displayed.

Here's my code:

```
$('#usbm').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                                type: 'scatter',
                                height:600,
                                width:600
                        },
                        title: {
                                text: 'Peak Particle Velocity Vs. Frequency'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                                min: 1,
                                max: 100,
                                type: 'logarithmic',
                                title: {
                                        text: "Frequency (Hz)"
                                },
                                labels: {
                                        overflow: 'justify'                 
                                },
                                tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                                minorTickInterval:.1,
                                gridLineWidth: 1
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                                min: 0.01,
                                max: 10,
                                type: 'logarithmic',
                                tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                                minorTickInterval:.1,
                                gridLineWidth: 1,
                                title: {
                                        text: 'Velocity (in/sec)'
                                },
                                labels: {
                                        overflow: 'justify'                         
                                }
                        },
                         plotOptions: {
                                scatter: {
                                        tooltip: {
                                                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                                                pointFormat: 'PPV: {point.y}in/sec<br>FREQ: {point.x}Hz'
                                        }
                                },
                                line: {

                                            tooltip: {
                                                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                                                    pointFormat: '{point.y}in/sec<br>FREQ: {point.x}Hz'
                                            }
                                    }
                        },
                        legend: {
                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                shadow: true
                        },
                        series:series
                        }, function(chart) 
                                    { // on complete

                                        chart.renderer.text('0.03 inches', 90,250)
                                                    .attr({
                                                        rotation: -30
                                                    })
                                                    .css({
                                                        color: '#000000',
                                                        fontSize: '16px'
                                                    })
                                                    .add();


                            });
```

and here's a fiddle with my actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/Pudge/9VV29/11/

Comment: See realted topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657487/high-charts-rendering-on-internet-explorer-10

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but doing everything in the answers doesn't change anything. I also tried putting my graph in a <div> outside of a table and that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you reproduce your example as live demo, including data / css etc, as jsfiddle in example?

Comment: I added a fiddle with my actual code and an actual data set that I have used.

Comment: Well in very simple example http://jsfiddle.net/LSX3p/ adding rows/cols inside table and pushing elemens seems to working fine. It is possible to isolate your example as simple demo of this problem?

Comment: I can't figure out how to isolate to simple problem, though I have figured out that changing the min and max so that there's 5 intervals allows it to work as it should. Example: my current min is .01 and my max is 10. If I change the min to .001 and leave my max the same or change the max to 100 and leave the min the same it renders fine. I can live with this, it's just frustrating.